# Setup Failed: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate x86(32-bit)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate it seems i got this error:.

[image]

Error Logs:

```
[01/23/15,09:07:20] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files are not available.
```

Comment: What is your installation media?

Comment: from the extraction of ISO files..

Comment: I simply extract the ISO Files to the desktop and manually installed it but it failed to install on my computer..

Comment: Do not extract the ISO files. Just mount the ISOs and install VS. Microsoft offers a free utility that can help you: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38780